# React Native ScrollView outer container style flex: value

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

It's possible to style the inner container (ala `background:'red') with` contentContainerStyle`:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{background:'red'}>
```

However, here is my attempt to style the outermost container (ala `flex:5`), something that works fine with a standard **<View>** component:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:5}}>
```

The second example fails to render the style on the outermost container. The style is applied to a child container nested inside the outermost.

How do I style the outermost container of a **<ScrollView>?**

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works specifically, in this case, is to place the **<ScrollView>** immediately inside a **<View>** component which serves as the container for a `flex:5` CSS instruction.

```
<View style={{flex:5}}>
  <ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think this is because ScrollView over-rides those values here https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/react-native/blob/4091984ff189b0b69deed0406327fdf84f7f9602/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L1849